# Extract characters from a string (Ant - Eclipse)

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, ant

I'm new to Ant and i need some help.
I'm receiving a string through an input (dir = 4.2.1), and I want to divide it and use like two variables (dir1 = 4.2 and dir2 = 4.2.1)

```
    <input message="Digite o nome do arquivo WAR que sera gerado: "
           defaultvalue="docflow"
           addproperty="nome">
    </input>

    <input message="Digite o caminho onde o WAR sera armazenado: "             
           addproperty="dir">
    </input>


   <mkdir dir="${docflow4-web-home}/${dir1}/${dir2}/deploy"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.

```
<project default="test">

    <target name="test">

        <property name="dir" value="4.2.1"/>

        <loadresource property="dir1">
          <string value="${dir}"/>
          <filterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
              <replaceregex pattern="(.*)\.[^\.]+" replace="\1"/>
            </tokenfilter>
          </filterchain>
        </loadresource>

        <echo message="${dir1}"/>
        <echo message="${dir}"/>

    </target>

</project>
```

Output:

```
test:
     [echo] 4.2
     [echo] 4.2.1
```

Alternatively, you could use [propertyregx](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) from antcontrib.

Comment: oh thank you very much, you saved me! I was trying to use antcontrib but i couldn't config it right on Eclipse.